# How to tell users to sign up with our technology partner during onboarding?

Tags: usability, onboarding

We are developing a mail campaign product on top of our Technology Partner (Say mailgun ) , The user who sign up for our product should sign up with Mailgun as well to send the campaigns from our product using their mailgun credentials.

My question is during onboarding process how do I tell or educate our users to sign up with our technology partner once they register with us?

Any suggestions is highly appreciated.

Comment: Is it absolutely required to sign up with the partner for your product to work or would it just be a better experience?

Comment: Yes Its absolutely required without that we cannot send emails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Which will be better usability if we ask users to do this signup in very first login or once they completed on boarding process of our Product?**

The best way will be to ask is after the completion of your on boarding process, because that will feel to be in the same context which is 'Sign-Up'. Asking to Sign-Up after login will be some what out of context as user already performed Login(no matter for what) than popping sign-up page after that feels quite awkward.

Answer (score 1):

Does your partner have an API? Why make the user sign up twice? If they sign up with you automatically create an account with Mailgun. It should be transparent.

Comment: They dont have any SAML or OAuth support to do this from our product . user has to manually create account in their site.

Comment: I agree with this idea, if youre website functionality relies on having an account with your partner then it should either be mandatory to already have an account with them (they sign up with their mailgun credentials) or when they create an account with you it is also created for mailgun. If they are your partner they should be able to accommodate this.

Answer (score 0):

"To send mailshots from [Product Name] you should sign into your Mailgun account. If you don't have a Mailgun account you can sign up here: [Link Address]"

Comment: Which will be better usability if we ask users to do this signup in very first login or once they completed on boarding process of our Product?